# How are Solidworks appearances handled during translation/viewing?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are having repeated challenges where a small number of components in a translated Solidworks model are being shown as transparent, They are still selectable and appear in the model tree. From my own experiments, it appears this is to do with appearance settings within the Solidworks models - with some being applied at an assembly level and some at component level. Is there any documentation/advice on how we should manage the appearances in Solidworks so we get full visiblity of parts in the viewer?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Sorry, it's hard for me to imagine what happened. Could you consider providing a reproducible model and snapshots demonstrating this issue? If it couldn't be posted here, please sent it to forge.help [AT] autodesk [DOT] com. **Note.** Please remove any confidential information and data from anything you want to send to us, cheers!

Comment: Hello, could you consider the above suggestion? I'm glad to help you pass it to our engineering team for investigating.